# In $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric, determine the closure of $A=(0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to determine the closure of $A=(0, 1]$, I will consider the most appropriate definition of closure for this problem to be $Cl(A)=\text{Int(A)} \cup \partial(A)$. In this case, I consider that $\text{Int(A)}=\text{Int}((0, 1])=(0, 1]$ because since for some radius $r$ and $a\in (0, 1]$, I think that $$r=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1-a & \text{if} \hspace{0.3cm} a<1\\ 
\frac{1}{2} & \text{if} \hspace{0.3cm} a=1
\end{matrix}\right.$$
It could work for $B(a; r) \subseteq (0, 1]$, the opposite contentment is considered to be the definition of interior.

This with respect to $\text{Int}((0, 1])$; we now know that $$\partial ((0, 1])=\mathbb{R}-(\text{Int}((0, 1]) \cup \text{Ext}((0, 1])=\mathbb{R}-((0, 1] \cup \text{Ext}((0, 1])$$ With respect to $\text{Ext}((0, 1])$ I interpret that it is $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(1, \infty)$. But I don't see clearly how to determine the border to finally find the closure, any suggestions? any help is welcome!

Comment: The interior of a set is always an open set, so $Int(A)$ definitely can't be $(0,1]$.

Comment: Int(A) is the largest open set contained in A. So, Int(A)=(0,1). Except this mistake, you have done correctly. Just take this interior, you will get boundary of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Int(A)= (0,1)$. Notice every point in $(0,1)$ has an open neighborhood contained in $A$. $\partial A=\{0,1\}$. This is due to the fact that $0$ (similarly 1), is a limit of points in $A$ (take e.g. $x_n = 1/n \to 0$) and is a limit of points in $A^c$ (take e.g. $y_n = -1/n \to 0$). In the language of neighborhoods, every neighborhood of $0$ must contain points in $A$ and $A^c$ (why)?

Comment: Perfect, now I understand that effectively every open ball with center at zero has points of $(0, 1]$ and its complement; for the first case it means that $b \in (-r, r)$, for all $r$ the radius in the ball, and also $b \in (0, 1]$, I can say that $-r<0<b<r \leq 1$? I don't really see how to write in the demonstration that effectively every open ball centered at zero has point of $A$.

Comment: That looks basically correct! Every ball centered at the $0$ is of the form $B=(-r,r)$. The point $r/2$ is in $A\cap B$. The point $-r/2 \in A \cap B^c$. As such every ball centered at 0 has a non-empty intersection with $A$ and $A^c$. Hence $0 \in \partial A$.